# InvalidArgumentException during Magento upgrade via Composer [Package is not installed: magento/project-community-edition-2.4.0.0]

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer

We are seeing `InvalidArgumentException during Magento upgrade via Composer`

```
 [InvalidArgumentException]
  Package is not installed: magento/project-community-edition-2.4.0.0
```

It seems to be related to the "replace" section of composer where a module is mentioned that does no longer exist in M2.4. But which one?

**Question:**
How could we get this to work? or find out more exact what is wrong?

Full log with update -vvv

```
Package operations: 0 installs, 2 updates, 0 removals
Updates: magento/project-community-edition:2.4.0, mailchimp/mc-magento2:102.3.41


  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Package is not installed: magento/project-community-edition-2.4.0.0


Exception trace:
 () at /usr/share/php/Composer/Installer/LibraryInstaller.php:114
 Composer\Installer\LibraryInstaller->update() at /usr/share/php/Composer/Installer/InstallationManager.php:193
 Composer\Installer\InstallationManager->update() at /usr/share/php/Composer/Installer/InstallationManager.php:160
 Composer\Installer\InstallationManager->execute() at /usr/share/php/Composer/Installer.php:611
 Composer\Installer->doInstall() at /usr/share/php/Composer/Installer.php:232
 Composer\Installer->run() at /usr/share/php/Composer/Command/UpdateCommand.php:163
 Composer\Command\UpdateCommand->execute() at /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:245
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:835
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:185
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php:281
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:117
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php:113
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at /usr/bin/composer:62

update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

[image]

References:
https://www.onooks.com/invalidargumentexception-during-magento-upgrade-via-composer/

```
Composer replace section
        "magento/module-marketplace": "*",
        "magento/module-admin-notification": "*",
        "magento/module-advanced-pricing-import-export": "*",
        "magento/module-amqp": "*",
        "magento/module-amqp-store": "*",
        "magento/module-analytics": "*",
        "magento/module-bundle-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-cardinal-commerce": "*",
        "magento/module-catalog-customer-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-catalog-analytics": "*",
        "magento/module-catalog-inventory-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-catalog-rule-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-checkout-agreements-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-customer-analytics": "*",
        "magento/module-customer-downloadable-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-dhl": "*",
        "magento/module-directory-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-downloadable": "*",
        "magento/module-downloadable-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-downloadable-import-export": "*",
        "magento/module-elasticsearch": "*",
        "magento/module-elasticsearch-6": "*",
        "magento/module-elasticsearch-7": "*",
        "magento/module-fedex": "*",
        "magento/module-gift-message-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-google-adwords": "*",
        "magento/module-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-graph-ql-cache": "*",
        "magento/module-catalog-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-catalog-cms-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-configurable-product-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-customer-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-eav-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-swatches-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-tax-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-url-rewrite-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-cms-url-rewrite-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-weee-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-cms-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-grouped-product-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-mysql-mq": "*",
        "magento/module-newsletter-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-paypal-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-quote-analytics": "*",
        "magento/module-quote-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-related-product-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-release-notification": "*",
        "magento/module-review-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-review-analytics": "*",
        "magento/module-sales-analytics": "*",
        "magento/module-sales-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-sample-data": "*",
        "magento/module-send-friend-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-store-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-swagger": "*",
        "magento/module-swagger-webapi": "*",
        "magento/module-swagger-webapi-async": "*",
        "magento/module-theme-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-ups": "*",
        "magento/module-usps": "*",
        "magento/module-vault-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-wishlist-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-wishlist-analytics": "*",
        "magento/language-de_de": "*",
        "magento/language-es_es": "*",
        "magento/language-fr_fr": "*",
        "magento/language-pt_br": "*",
        "magento/language-zh_hans_cn": "*",
        "magento/framework": "*",
        "magento/framework-amqp": "*",
        "magento/framework-bulk": "*",
        "magento/framework-message-queue": "*",
        "magento/module-dhl": "*",
        "magento/module-fedex": "*",
        "magento/module-authorizenet": "*",
        "magento/module-google-adwords": "*",
        "magento/module-sample-data": "*",
        "magento/module-swagger": "*",
        "magento/module-swagger-webapi": "*",
        "magento/module-swagger-webapi-async": "*",
        "magento/module-ups": "*",
        "magento/module-usps": "*",
        "magento/module-braintree": "*",
        "magento/module-signifyd": "*",
        "magento/module-release-notification": "*",
        "magento/module-analytics": "*",
        "magento/module-catalog-analytics": "*",
        "magento/module-customer-analytics": "*",
        "magento/module-quote-analytics": "*",
        "magento/module-review-analytics": "*",
        "magento/module-sales-analytics": "*",
        "magento/module-wishlist-analytics": "*",
        "magento/module-bundle-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-catalog-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-catalog-inventory-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-cms-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-cms-url-rewrite-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-configurable-product-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-customer-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-downloadable-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-eav-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-grouped-product-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-quote-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-store-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-swatches-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-tax-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-url-rewrite-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-weee-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-amqp": "*",
        "magento/module-amqp-store": "*",
        "dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension": "*",
        "dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-package": "*",
        "dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-enterprise": "*",
        "dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-chat": "*",
        "klarna/module-kp": "*",
        "klarna/module-ordermanagement": "*",
        "klarna/module-core": "*",
        "amzn/amazon-pay-sdk-php": "*",
        "amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-with-amazon-core-module": "*",
        "amzn/login-with-amazon-module": "*",
        "amzn/amazon-pay-module": "*",
        "amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-magento-2-module": "*",
        "vertex/module-tax": "*",
        "vertex/sdk": "*"
```

Answer (score 1):

- Remove "replace" section in composer.json
- Run composer install
- Reset "replace" section
- Compare your list with your vendors, and remove non existing ones from "replace" section